# Not able to authenticate my dev org from VS code

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I am getting below error while I am trying to authenticate my dev org from VS code:

```
{ Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs:
   [ '/c',
     'start',
     '""',
     '/b',
     'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=f2d46b6dff25^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=iWMVV8vXEuAAHd_zg3ONaCnBsa4OA1PAfBdz_8rzixs' ] }
```

Please help me out to fix this issue

Comment: Do not use project default, try custom and enter your dev url there

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to try changing your default browser to IE or Firefox? We face this issue when Chrome is the default browser.